# How to sort in descending order by extension method?

Tags: c#, linq

```
mylist.OrderBy(p => p.Description);
```

Propably ascending - what about descending?

Comment: `OrderBy` doesn't sort a list - it returns a new sequence, which (if you want) you can convert to a list. The statement you posted does nothing useful because you aren't assigning the result anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `OrderByDescending` / `ThenByDescending`

Answer (score 2):

**Why create Extension Method when it is available!!**

```
mylist.OrderByDescending(p => p.Description);
```

What you are using will order in ascending order. To order in descending order use `OrderByDescending`.